# Issues running Graph queries after upgrading Spark 2.4.3 to 3.1.3

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, scala-spark

We are upgrading the Scala Spark

Spark from 2.4.3 to 3.1.3
scalaVersion from 2.11.8 to 2.12.10
spark-cassandra-connector from 2.4.2 to 3.1.0
Cassandra version 3.2 and all the subsequent dependancies.

We are facing following issues,

```
[error] cassandra/CatalogConnector.scala:20:16: overloaded method value execute with alternatives:

[error]   (x$1: com.datastax.dse.driver.api.core.graph.GraphStatement[_])com.datastax.dse.driver.api.core.graph.GraphResultSet <and>

[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: Object*)com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.ResultSet <and>
[error]   (x$1: String)com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.ResultSet <and>
[error]   (x$1: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.Statement[_])com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.ResultSet
[error]  cannot be applied to (com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select)
[error]               .execute(
[error]                ^
```

We tried different option but did not help

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. I highly recommend https://stackoverflow.com/tour to familiarise yourself with the site. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this error message:

```
[error]   (x$1: com.datastax.dse.driver.api.core.graph.GraphStatement[_])com.datastax.dse.driver.api.core.graph.GraphResultSet <and>
```

I'm going to assume that you are connecting to a [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) cluster using an older DSE Java driver but are now trying to connect using the open-source Cassandra Java driver.

In any case, the latest version of [DSE 6.8 ships with Apache Spark 2.4](https://github.com/datastax/release-notes/blob/master/DSE_6.8_Release_Notes.md#components-versions-for-dse-6832) so it is not compatible with Apache Spark 3.1. Consequently, you need to use the Spark Cassandra connector that ships with DSE because the open-source version 3.1.0 of the connector is not compatible with DSE.

I have to admit, I am not sure this is the issue you are facing due to the very little information you provided. As a rule, you need to provide more details about the problem you're facing, your environment, a minimal sample code, and steps to replicate the issue. Cheers!